# Array not printing when Console.log is used

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I use the Alert it's working. But When I use Console.log it doesn't print anything.

I tried switching the alert with the console.log

```js
var myColor = ["Red", "Green", "White", "Black"];

for (i = 0; i < myColor.length; i++) {
    console.log(myColor);
}
```

Comment: It works here. You must be doing something different in your code.

Comment: Use the loop variable `console.log(myColor[i])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the syntax a bit 
var myColor = ["Red", "Green", "White", "Black"];

```
for (i = 0; i < myColor.length; i++) {
    console.log(myColor[i]);
}
```

Alternately you can also use for...of loop to print colors

```
var myColor = ["Red", "Green", "White", "Black"];
    for(const color of myColor){
    console.log(color);
    }
```